# creating a .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I am using Texmaker on a Mac. I am having trouble creating a bibliography.

Firstly, how do I create a file with the `.bib` extension? When I try to save a new file - let's call it "ref" - it saves as a `.tex` file. There is no option in "Save As" for `.bib`. In "Save As" when choosing extension time there is only one option which is "TeX Files( `.tex`, `.bib`, ...)".

Secondly, I understand that I am supposed to compile using PDFLatex>BibTex>PDFLatex>PDFLatex>ViewPDF. But I get error commands such as "exited with erros" when running `bibtex`. I am pasting the error message here:

> `\bibdata{ref : }` I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no cite keys---while reading file Impact of schooling on slum children_Summary_v1.aux I found no database files---while reading file Impact of schooling on slum children_Summary_v1.aux (There were 5 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

When using `beamer`, do we use the same method to create a bibliography?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Also, you might want to read [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: Also, I don't use TeXMaker, so I'm not sure how it works, but for managing a `.bib` file, you should use something like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) or [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/). BibDesk is Mac only. You can also just use any text editor, though, to create a `.bib` file, but a dedicated GUI like one of those is probably better.

Comment: You should just type the `.bib` extension manually.

Comment: In addition to Werner's statement, select in the "Save-As" dialog in "Filter" the option "All Files", then you can provide any file name and extension allowed by your OS.

Comment: Hi ...Thanks. I tried that. But same problems persists. So the command I am using is: \documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5]{fullpage}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}...\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{ref} ... Any idea what I am doing wrong? Do I need to change something in the settings of texmaker?

Comment: @SKn: Please add a minimal working example to your original post above instead a mere comment. See  (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for instance on how to make a MWE

Comment: `I found no cite keys...`. Did you actually cite anything in your document?